# Anchor tag is not working in safari iphone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ios

Let me first add the anchor tag code

```
<a id="store_follow" 
    class="primary-button" 
    data-user-action='on' 
    data-id='<?php echo $value->storeId;?>' 
    data-mode='<?php echo UserUtils::ACTION_MODE_STORE_FOLLOW;?>' 
    data-toggle="true" 
    data-callback="_obs_follow_stores"
> Follow </a>
```

PHP is being used with this and this button works on all browser in all devices except safari in iphone.

When someone clicks on follow if user is logged in it will follow that thing and button will change to unfollow

If user is not logged in then it will open the login window popup for user.

What could be wrong with this ?

On unfollow button I am doing actions using onclick event from javascript and jquery ajax call so it's working

But in above button calling happening from PHP side.

What needs to changed to make it work on iphone safari ?

Unfollow code

```
<a class="primary-button active" onclick="unfollowStore('<?php echo $value->storeId;?>');"> Unfollow </a>
```

I can't do onclick on follow because PHP and I am just modifying this project.

Comment: I've a doubt. you don't use the `href` ,is that a problem

Comment: @JishnuVS I think so

Comment: The `href` attribute specifies the link's destination, so it would be more like a link of another page. but in my case it's button action like facebook add friend

Comment: Need more debugging info than just *"doesn't work"*. Errors? What does `unfollowStore()` do?

Comment: @charlietfl how do you debug in iphone ?

Comment: unfollowStore is a ajax call it'll unfollow the particular store and button will replace with follow again

Comment: *"how do you debug in iphone"* ... did you ask google or your favorite search engine?

Comment: Yeah did but I don't have another iOS device to do the process

Comment: Thanks anyways Jishnu was right and so was Huy. Thanks Charlie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `href` attribute to your tag and return false from your `onclick` method.

```
<a href="#" class="primary-button active" onclick="unfollowStore('<?php echo $value->storeId;?>');return false;"> Unfollow </a>
```

I know you said it works in all browsers but I have seen numerous times on desktop browsers where onclick does not work in an `<a>` tag when it does not have an `href` set.

If it still doesn't work try firing a different JavaScript method. Your code might be causeing causing a JavaScript error.

To alleviate the latter make sure your `unfollowStore` function or any other method is wrapped in a `try {} catch{}` block.

Comment: My unfollowStore function has no issues. I am sorry you misunderstood the question. Follow is not working. See the first code snippet in question

Comment: Okay still you're right and `href="#"` solved my problem, didn't it was this important.